# Does this equivalence stand?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm struggling to verify the following equivalence from [Ekeland](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783642743337) (p.12):

$$\lambda (\xi \cosh t + \overline \xi \sinh t) = \lambda e^t (\xi + \overline \xi)$$

for $\lambda=\pm 1$ and $\xi \in \mathbb C^n$

Comment: Where are you stuck?  Have you separated $\sinh,\cosh$ into exponential form?

Comment: Thank you @abiessu. So you say it's just $e^t = cosht + sinh t$? It is an alternative form of the exponential I wasn't aware of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\xi=i$, $\lambda=1$:
$$
\xi\cosh(t)+\bar{\xi}\sinh(t)=i(\cosh(t)-\sinh(t))=ie^{-t}\neq 0
$$

Hence the relation is false.